# Getting wrong time for timestamp field with hibernate select

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, postgresql

**Getting wrong time for timestamp field with Hibernate select.**

---

We are using Hibernate framework and [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/) database.

We have a table which stores 'created_time' in column of data type [TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).

```
+------------------------------------------+
+ created_time +
+------------------------------------------+
+ 2014-09-22 04:30:00.756 +
+ -----------------------------------------+
```

Assume we have a data **'2014-09-22 04:30:00.756'** in '**created_time**'.

I used the following hibernate query

```
query= "SELECT column1,column2,createdTime FROM TableName";
…
…
List<Object[]> dataList=selectQuery.list();
for(Object data[] : dataList)
{
System.out.println("Date and time -> "+data[2].toString()); //Time coming wrong here
}
```

When I go throught the dataList I find that the date is coming correctly, but the **time is something else like '11:45:00.345'**.

The same query if I used in [pgAdminIII](http://www.pgadmin.org/) means it is coming correctly.

But with hibernate it is coming wrongly.

I have even tried SQL query. Still I face the wrong time problem.

I am not getting a solution when i searched the net.

Comment: Did you find any solutions with your problem?

Answer (score 1):

probably you are getting the local time zone instead of the server timezone.
So to get the timestamp of server as it is , change your query to something like below:

```
query= "SELECT column1,column2,createdTime at time zone current_setting('TIMEZONE') FROM TableName";
```

Comment: Correct. Postgres converts and stores the date-time value to UTC. By default, upon retrieval the current default time zone is applied and the adjusted value returned to the client (pgAdmin for you). The `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is a misnomer as the time zone info is *not* stored. A better name would have been `TIMESTAMP WITH RESPECT FOR TIME ZONE`. So for retrieval specify your desired time zone, be that UTC or a local [time zone name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 1):

It is a common problem when we want to read/write dates from DB and store them in UTC time zone. For example in case of reading from DB a date with time `9:54` using Hibernate, thanks to JDBC, we get a `9:54` time, but interpreted as a local date; for me it would be `9:54 UTC+2`. This means that on Java side we just got `7:54 UTC` time. There is a better explanation of this issue in this [article](http://blog.montrosesoftware.com/2016/11/08/dates-and-times-in-java-unexpected-timezone-shift/).

Anyway, you can easily fix it by using a small `DbAssist` open source library. It maps the standard `Date` fields to a custom `UtcDateType`, which forces Hibernate to treat dates as UTC. You can find more details about the supported Hibernate versions and installation guide on project's [github wiki](https://github.com/montrosesoftware/DbAssist/wiki).

If you are using JPA annotations to map entities, just add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.montrosesoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>DbAssist-5.2.2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Applying the fix is really simple; for example, if you are using `persistence.xml` file with your Hibernate, just add a single line inside `persistence-unit` tag:

```
<class>com.montrosesoftware.dbassist.types</class>
```

For other Hibernate configurations, e.g with Spring Boot, refer to the github project page. Anyway, the fix works instantly after this step and now all the dates read from (and saved to) the DB through Hibernate are treated as UTC.